# jpa : how to use jpa in java se development

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I am working on  a java se project which use jpa to persist data with database.

Right now i get a new entity manager for each database operation and close it when function call end. like

```
public void save(T entity){
  em = getNewEntity();
  em.persisty(entity);
  em.close;
}
```

but its very hard to manager the many-to-many relationship.
for example
i have A entity who have a many-to-many relationship with B entity.
and they have CascadeType.MERGE.

once i create A, i create B , and run multiple thread to generate information for both A and B.
but sometime B keep the outdated of A, if i merge B then A's data will be purged.

for example . A is music , B is music album , so one B will have a A list. Another thread will read music metadata and get music tag info and update  A , B will be updated when a new A found in the FS.
Since entity manager closed , the entities in  B's A list is out of date which means when A update itself , B doesn't know A updated . Once Merge B , jpa will help us merge A using the entity in B 's A list.

in order to solve this problem, i decide to use one entity manager and put all database operation into one single thread.  Then new problem comes out.

when the transaction is active and the transaction is supposed to open for the entity between

```
transaction.begin();
....
transaction.end();
```

however there are many threads running , and those thread may change entity too.

my question is:
  how to use jpa in java se development ?. thanks

Comment: I'd say this is not a specific JPA issue, it's just about multithreading. You have to properly synchronize wherever you need to...

Comment: synchronize cannot solve this ... when the transaction is turn on i cannot block other thread...

Comment: But you have to if you want to synchronize on certain information. I do not fully understand your application, but you might need to work with just one EntityManager instance and use e.g. `java.util.concurrent.ReentrantReadWriteLock` to control your data access layer...

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089411/jpa-applicationmanaged-entitymanager-for-jse-to-control-transaction-lifecycle

Comment: thanks for the reply. my problem is , for example, the DB service thread named Thread A, and other threads who keep entities named Thread N. So i turn on transaction in Thread A, this transaction is supposed to use in Thread A. However, entity manager doesn't know entity belong to which thread, then entity in Thread N may also use this transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship gets out of sync, you cannot blame JPA. It is the application's responsibility to keep the relationship sane.

> In JPA, as in Java in general it is the responsibility of the application, or the object model to maintain relationships.

[Source](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side)

As @home said, you need to synchronize properly.

That being said, the EntityManager is not thread safe so you need to solve this in some way. Synchronize your application, use one EntityManager per thread, use @PersistenceContext, etc.

Edit: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930280/synchronize-access-to-jpa-entitymanager) is a question asked about synchrinizing access to the EntityManager. I think it may be of use to you.